# In bash, how do I read a file and pass its content to be an environment variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

I have a file with content:

```
EnableSchemaValidation="False"
EnableRedshiftImport="True"
```

how do I run a bash/shell command to parse this file and set environment variables as:

```
√ ~ % echo ${EnableSchemaValidation}
False
√ ~ % echo ${EnableRedshiftImport}
True
√ ~ %
```

Comment: `source myEnvFile` ? You can do this on the cmd-line OR include it in a script just before you need your envVars, OR more commonly at/near the top of your script. With a script you may need to make the location/path of the file an envVar (as well) OR just hard-code it , i.e. `source /path/to/myEnvFile`. Good luck.

Comment: Per your topic message "read file, pass contents to env var", I had assumed you meant you needed `envVar=$(< /path/to/file_With_value_only_Contents)` . In your case where `/path/to/file...` has just the value `False`, you would do `EnableRedshiftImport=$(< /path/to/file...)`. Good luck.

Comment: Is the file's content _actually valid bash source_? (That's true for the lines you showed, but using `source` or equivalent requires that it be true universally, and risks security problems otherwise).

Comment: btw, saying you want to parse the file into "an" environment variable when you actually want a separate environment variable per line of the file is a bit misleading.

Comment: And if it's not in valid bash syntax, you need to define what its syntax is before this question can be answered.

Comment: @shellter: For the example data, this would not make the variables **environment** variables.

Comment: You just gave an **example** of how this file could look like. You would have to specify in general the syntax of this file in order to get a reasonable answer. For the concrete example which you have posted, it would be sufficient to prepend each line of the file with `export ` and then source the file.